# 3d surface plot genfromtxt

Tags: python, 3d

I was facing a problem in plotting a 3d surface plot by reading a text file. The problem is, I am using a different datatypes, like float, int and string.. I have attached the code with the sample data to be parsed.. I would appreciate with any comments with the code to make it functional...

The error which I got now is ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.

Thnx in advance....

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from numpy import genfromtxt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') #ax = Axes3D(fig) 
ax.set_title("Plot 3d",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Voltage (V)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Pulse Delay(ms)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_zlabel('Pulse Width(ms)', fontsize=12)
ax.grid(True, linestyle='-', color='0.75')
x,y,z,m =genfromtxt('sample.txt', dtype=[('col1', 'f15'), ('col2', 'i15'), ('col3',   'i15'), ('col4', 'S15')],  unpack=True)

use_colours = []
for tmp in m:
    if tmp=='PASS':
        use_colours.append('g')
    else:
        use_colours.append('r')

ax.scatter(x,y,z, s=50, c=use_colours, marker = 'o', linewidths=0);
plt.show()



sample.txt

6.000000    15.000000   21.000000   PASS
6.000000    15.000000   53.000000   PASS
6.000000    15.000000   91.000000   PASS
6.000000    15.000000   104.000000  PASS
```

Comment: Looking at your code and the error you are getting, your first issue is due to the values of x, y and z. These variables should contain an array of values corresponding to the x, y or z values of each point. Instead your x, y and z result in data that looks like:

x = (6.0, 15, 21, 'PASS')

y = (6.0, 15, 53, 'PASS')

z = (6.0, 15, 91, 'PASS')

Comment: Actually the sample.txt is just a sample of my data.. I have more than 50,000 lines to be parsed.. So the issue I feel is with datatype field .. suggest me any improvements in the datatype.. The same code I followed for 2d plot and it works fine...

Comment: I am more than reasonably sure that your problem is not in your dtype parameter as I've run an edited version of your code using it and it functioned properly. I think your problem is in using the unpack=True flag. This is transposing the resultant array so that each row is unpacked into each variable(as opposed to each column). If I omit the unpack=True flag and, instead, manually unpack each column into an array everything works properly. I'll dump the code in an answer below for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to execute your code, I have discovered some misuse that is difficult to prevent without knowing the correct functioning of `matplotlib` libraries.

Here is a commented code that works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))

ax = Axes3D(fig) # ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_title("Plot 3d",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Voltage (V)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Pulse Delay(ms)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_zlabel('Pulse Width(ms)', fontsize=12)
ax.grid(True, linestyle='-', color='0.75')

# 'i15' and 'f15' are not known as numerical types.
# You can use only 'i8' (np.int64) and 'f16' (np.float128) or 'f8' (np.float64).
# 'f16' seems not to be recognized as a valid type for the scatter library.
# I think that 'f8' and 'i8' are quoit enough.
data = np.genfromtxt('./sample.txt', dtype=[('col1', 'f8'), ('col2', 'i8'), ('col3',   'i8'), ('col4', 'S15')])

# scatter does not take for the c option a list of colours such as ['g', 'g', 'r', ...].
# In this case, we will define data for each colour, not a color for each scatter point.
m = data["col4"]
data1 = data[m == "PASS"]
data2 = data[m != "PASS"]

for dat, color in [(data1, 'g'), (data2, 'r')]:
    # Don't forget that having empty data columns may raise exceptions ...
    try:
        x, y, z = dat['col1'], dat['col2'], dat['col3']
        ax.scatter(xs=x, ys=y, zs=z, s=50, c=color, marker='o', linewidths=0)
    except:
        pass

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thnks for the corrcetions...The code is working fine with f16 too..  It helped quite a lot to work out my task.....

Comment: Hello Taha, I have some problems in the same code.. I would like to extend the code by adding extra columns.. like sample as                       7.020000 993.000000 913.000000 FAIL [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 ],
7.020000 993.000000 954.000000 FAIL [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 ]. Now the  issue is that, i need to take all the items within box braces [] as one column like total colums as 5. How to write an condition to proceed with it? Any suggestions would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The error code you are getting suggests that at some point you are passing in information that does not fit the variables. This appears to be coming from the unpack=true flag in your genfromtxt call. Looking at some of the docs regarding genfromtxt it appears that using the unpack=True flag will result in "the returned array is transposed, so that arguments may be unpacked using x, y, z = loadtxt(...)" which, ultimatly is resulting in your x, y, z and m values looking like:

```
x = (6.0, 15, 21, 'PASS') 
y = (6.0, 15, 53, 'PASS') 
z = (6.0, 15, 91, 'PASS')
m = (6.0, 15, 104, 'PASS')
```

These values will not work with what you have in your code obviously. Interestingly this only works if you have 4 lines in your sample.txt and are trying to unpack 4 variables.

A solution to this is to not flag unpack=true. Instead something like this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

## takes a matrix and a column index, returns a list of the values
## in that column
def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') #ax = Axes3D(fig) 
ax.set_title("Plot 3d",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Voltage (V)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Pulse Delay(ms)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_zlabel('Pulse Width(ms)', fontsize=12)
ax.grid(True, linestyle='-', color='0.75')

## Your original call
#x,y,z,m =genfromtxt('sample.txt', delimiter="""", dtype=[('col1', 'f15'),
##('col2','i15'), ('col3',   'i15'), ('col4', 'S15')],  unpack=True)

## The modified call
data = np.genfromtxt('sample.txt', 
                     delimiter='\t', 
                     usecols=(0,1,2,3),
                     dtype=[('col1', 'f15'), 
                           ('col2', 'i15'), 
                           ('col3', 'i15'), 
                           ('col4', 'S15')])

## split the data so that each column in the 2d array ends up in a variable.
## There is a numpy way of doing this, you should look into that
x = column(data, 0)
y = column(data, 1)
z = column(data, 2)
m = column(data, 3)

use_colours = []
for tmp in m:
    if tmp=='PASS':
        use_colours.append('g')
    else:
        use_colours.append('r')

## Let's make sure the values look like we expect:
print x
print "\n"
print y
print "\n"
print z
print "\n"
print m

ax.scatter(x,y,z, s=50, c=use_colours, marker = 'o', linewidths=0);
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thnx Nahkki, for ur support.. The code works fine surprisingly with 1 lakh lines too...:)

Comment: Hello Nahkki, I have some problems in the same code.. I would like to extend the code by adding extra columns.. like sample as 7.020000 993.000000 913.000000 FAIL [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 ], 7.020000 993.000000 954.000000 FAIL [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 ]. Now the issue is that, i need to take all the items within box braces [] as one column like total columns as 5. How to write an condition to proceed with it? Any suggestions would be helpful...